# What "sql:"-"" represents in Go lang GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

In this [article](https://medium.com/@adigunhammedolalekan/build-and-deploy-a-secure-rest-api-with-go-postgresql-jwt-and-gorm-6fadf3da505b), the blogger writes the code for his GORM model as below

```
type Account struct {
gorm.Model
Email string `json:"email"`
Password string `json:"password"`
Token string `json:"token";sql:"-"`
}
```

I am not sure what **sql:"-"** represents in this model? Couldn't get results in google aswell. I am new to GO, help on this would be appreciatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old version of GORM, `sql:"-"` means ignore that field. The new version of GORM uses `gorm:"-"` instead. [here](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#model-definition)